# CGI script showing as plain text

Tags: apache, perl, cgi, vagrant, cgi-bin

I have done the following checks:

- shebang line
- file extension .cgi
- script is executable
- restarted apache

I've done the following in my project.conf file on Vagrant under /sites-enabled:

```
<Directory /var/www/perl_project/cgi-bin>
      Options ExecCGI
      SetHandler cgi-script
</Directory>
```

I'm pointing to  `http://project.local/cgi-bin/routes.cgi?page=reports` in my links, but they bring up the text of the script and don't run them...

The script isn't displaying any HTML, it is a kind of router where I get query string and based on that load a template toolkit file

could someone please help?

Comment: Anything in your apache error log? Does your apache config have `mod_cgi` turned on?

Comment: @friedo I don't see any errors in my apache error log. where would i turn the mod_cgi module on, or where would i check to see if it is on? I don't see the httpd.conf file in my vagrant box, not sure where it is

Comment: i found this file: 'cgi.load' in the 'mods-available' directory, it isn't commented out, but it also isn't in the mods-enabled directory. Should it be?

Comment: I enabled two modules: cgid and cgi, not sure what to do now :/

Comment: Any idea where i should be putting the following: ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/local/apache2/cgi-bin/ ? Sorry this stuff is really baffling me

Comment: Did you try restarting apache after enabling `mod_cgi`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I placed my cgi scripts under `/usr/lib/cgi-bin`

After installing the mod_cgi module I noticed a `/cgi-bin` directory was created under `/vagrant`, but that didn't work for some reason so I hunted down the former `cgi-bin` directory.

Hope this helps someone